# NJM78L09UA alternative

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a circuit specifying a fixed 9V positive regulator; [NJM78L09UA](http://www.njr.com/semicon/PDF/NJM78L00_E.pdf)  (9V 0.1mA)

The component seems to be a bit hard to get hold of. Would like to ask advice for more common alternatives. As I'm fresh on circuit design, I don't really have any overview..

Should be SMD, ideally SOT89.

Purpose: regulator for supply by either a 9V battery or wall adapter.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua78l09a.pdf

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/L78L09ACUTR/497-1192-1-ND

Comment: @JohnD I saw ua78l09a says min Vin 11.5V, but will it perform also at lower input, like a 9V battery?

Comment: A linear regulator requires some "headroom" in order to regulate properly.  Older conventional regulators like these usually need close to 3V (11.5V for 9V out in this case.)  Your original part will have the same issue.  If you truly need 9V out from a 9V battery you should investigate a buck-boost switching regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find equivalents at Digikey or Mouser, and others, as the links above indicate.

A 9V battery cannot give you a stable 9V output with a linear regulator such as an LM78L09. If the current is modest, a 5V output (using LM78L05) is possible with reasonable battery life. [Here](http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/indexerfiles/Datasheets-SL6/DSASL00110019.pdf), from a typical alkaline 9V cell, you can see the lifetime vs. EOL voltage.

[image]

A 78L05 would give you 5V with maybe 40 hours life with 10mA (including the few mA the regulator draws) but a better LDO regulator could give you more like 75 hours life (and closer to 90 hours if it was a low power CMOS type). At $2/battery the better regulator pays for itself pretty quickly.

Comment: Circuit draws 1mA average by pulsed (1us width, 100Hz) capacitor partial discharge. Lower dropout voltage would be desirable over LDOs which looks to drop 1.5V. But I have trouble identifying LDOs or CMOS for 9V giving lower dropout. Any examples?

Comment: LDO won't help you if you need 9V and only have 9V. If you can use 5V I can help, otherwise you need a higher input voltage or a lower voltage circuit.

Comment: No I don't need 9V, but as high as possible, capped to ~9V for alternative supply by 12V power adapter instead of battery. I suppose then it's best to use a 9V regulator and get 7.5 (when on 9V battery), or you mean it will not function well below typical input?  Of course, if I can get lower dropout IC to increase output towards 9V, that is preferable.

Comment: I understand the output will be 7.5V when battery-supplied and 9V when adapter-supplied (12V). That's ok. But better if I can get both at approx 9V.

Comment: The [LM2931](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/LM2931-D.PDF)  is one of the more popular very mature bipolar parts. You can use the adjustable version and pick the voltage by choosing resistors. Various packages. Only a bit more complex to use than the LM79L09.

Answer (score 1):

The 78L00 series are mostly generic parts. Tossing "78L09" into a distributor's search box should net you many, many replacements.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about your 78L09 part. Any other one designated as 78L09 should work in this application. Well, it will work just as bad as the original part did. Just measure the output voltage of that L09 regulator when fed from a 9V battery. You will be disappointed.